# WCF web service method dying on https, works on http

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I have an old WCF web service method which execute 10-20 minutes. 
It's written on vb.net 4.0
I use SoapUI application to test it, and self written vb.net app which consume it.
On my localhost when I run it in Debug mode with IIS Express, I'm getting results back in both application.
But on QA web server, under https, I'm getting error back:

SoapUI error: Error getting response; java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.

From my web client: "An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://qa.organization.com/services/Blah.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details." Inner Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. Inner Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Web engineer run trace on web server, got and error "An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection".

Please advise what else I can check in order to fix this issue?

From web service web.config:

```
    <binding name="Blah_1" 
             closeTimeout="00:12:00" 
             openTimeout="00:12:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:30:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:30:00" 
             allowCookies="false"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Text" 
             textEncoding="utf-8" 
             transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1000" 
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
                   proxyCredentialType="None"
                   realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                 algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26696679/6677731) This may help you .

Answer (score 0):

Add the protocol mapping in the config file:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
```