# WCF Web Service not able to connect using https

Tags: c#, https, wcf-binding

> Been pulling hair out for a week now trying to get a existing, working
> web service to work unber https. The web service advertises fine while
> under https but when trying to interact thru client it fails. I have
> read everything and tried so many combinations of app.config and web
> configs and need more eyes. Here is what I have.
>
> App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

> Web.Config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
  <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IScanDocumentWcf" />
</protocolMapping>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000000" />
</diagnostics>
<bindings>
<basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IScanDocumentWcf" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MySiteLibrary.Services.ScanDocumentWcf" behaviorConfiguration="serviceHttpsBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="MySiteLibrary.Services.IScanDocumentWcf" />       
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceFaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="serviceHttpsBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

</system.serviceModel>

> Error Returned
>
> ```
>     There was no endpoint listening at https://webscan.MySite.com/ScanDocumentWcf.svc that could accept the
> ```
>
> message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
> See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
> at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message
> message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
> TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
> message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)    at IScanDocumentWcf.GetScanForms()    at
> ScanDocumentWcfClient.GetScanForms()
>
> Inner Exception: Unable to connect to the remote server    at
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
>
> Inner Exception: A connection attempt failed because the connected
> party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
> 195.168.2.145:443    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
> System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
> Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
> ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
> exception)

Answer (score 0):

The web service has a significant impact on whether HTTP or HTTPS is used.

You can take a look at the link below and find some useful information:
[WCF service not working when accessed over HTTPS and HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558326/wcf-service-not-working-when-accessed-over-https-and-http).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved when I changed the service name to the same name as the Contract.

<service name="MySiteLibrary.Services.ScanDocumentWcf" to
<service name="IScanDocumentWcf"